# How to modify full text of some columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I got a fairly big dataframe from a csv in pandas.

The problem is that on some columns I get strings of text which I would like to isolate the last character to turn it into integers.

I found a solution, but I am fairly sure it's not the most efficient.
It goes like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("filename")

cols = list(df.loc[:, 'col_a':'column_s'])
df_filtered = df[cols].dropna()

df_filtered['col_o'] = df_filtered['col_o'].str[-1:]
df_filtered['col_p'] = df_filtered['col_p'].str[-1:]
df_filtered['col_q'] = df_filtered['col_q'].str[-1:]
df_filtered['col_r'] = df_filtered['col_r'].str[-1:]
df_filtered['col_s'] = df_filtered['col_s'].str[-1:]
```

In terms of writing, this is not really efficient. So I've tried something like this:

```
colstofilter = list(df_filtered.loc[:, 'col_o':'col_s'])

for col in df_filtered[colstofilter]:
    print(df_filtered[col].str[-1:].head())
```

Printing it gives exactly what I want, but when I try to turn it into a function or a lamba or apply it to the dataframe, I get an error that it's not supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_filtered.loc[:, 'col_o':'col_s'] = \
    df_filtered.loc[:, 'col_o':'col_s'].apply(lambda x: x.str[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

df = pd.DataFrame(
    'ABC', list('xyz'),
     list(ascii_lowercase[:10])
).add_prefix('col_')

df

  col_a col_b col_c col_d col_e col_f col_g col_h col_i col_j
x   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC
y   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC
z   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC
```

***`update` + `loc` + `stack`/`str`/`unstack`***
`stack` to make one series so we can call `str` just once.
`unstack` to bring it back to a dataframe.
`update` to update `df` in place

```
df.update(df.loc[:, 'col_d':'col_g'].stack().str[-1].unstack())

df

  col_a col_b col_c col_d col_e col_f col_g col_h col_i col_j
x   ABC   ABC   ABC     C     C     C     C   ABC   ABC   ABC
y   ABC   ABC   ABC     C     C     C     C   ABC   ABC   ABC
z   ABC   ABC   ABC     C     C     C     C   ABC   ABC   ABC
```